# How to add new framework version in Installment Requirement page of InstallShield?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

As you see from **Project Assistant->Installment Requirement** screenshot of **InstallShield**, It is showing only till .NET Framework 4.6 in the list.

How do I add other frameworks like 4.7 and above?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own custom prerequisite. Just look at all the settings for 4.6, copy them to the new prerequisite and modify accordingly (e.g. registry entries, file paths etc.) to reflect the new version. To verify registry entries and file paths, you will need to have .NET 4.7 installed on a test system. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: where I can see the settings for existing prerequisites?

Comment: What version of InstallShield are you using? In IS 2016, If you right-click on existing prerequisite (e.g. .NET 4.6) and select "Edit Prerequisite..." from the context menu, you will see all the properties, conditions, files to include etc.

Comment: I tried both IS limited edition and IS 2018. None has context menu :(

Comment: check if you have any .prq files in C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\20xx\SetupPrerequisites. If so, you can just  clone exising .prq file for .NET and make changes in any text editor. I'm not sure if Limited Edition supports prerequisite editing, but from the full version you should be able to select Tools > Prerequisite Editor from the main menu

Comment: I have IS 2015 LE in VS 2013 running under Win 10 and wish to add condition to check for .Net 4.6. The folder C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2015LE\SetupPrerequisites has prq files for .Net 4.6 Full and .Net 4.6 Web  but these do not appear in the list in Installation Requirements, which stops at .Net 4.5 Full package. How can I get .Net 4.6 added to the list?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like higher versions of the .NET framework has not been added yet - even in the latest version `Installshield 2018`.

Essentially this menu choice looks like it just adds a registry search and a launch condition. This you can create yourself. The following MSDN article describes how to detect versions of the .NET framework: [.NET Framework deployment guide for developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/deployment-guide-for-developers#detecting-the-net-framework).

Here is a quick mock-up:

In the **RegLocator table**, add this row:

`DotNet471Full, 2, SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full, Release, 2`

This will target the 32-bit section of the registry on a 64-bit machine. This is how Installshield sets up the check for the previous versions of the framework, so I use that.

In the **AppSearch table**, add this row:

`DOTNETVERSION471FULL, DotNet471Full`

In the **LaunchCondition table**, add this row (see note below on the default Installshield condition - I have extended it here to alleviate some potential problems):

`Installed OR DOTNETVERSION471FULL>="#461308", Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 Full package or greater needs to be installed for this installation to continue.`

This should show a message notifying the user about the missing pre-requisite .NET framework. However, is it really necessary to check for the latest version? Doesn't it all target the same CLR (version 4)?

---

**A note on testing**: Please test thoroughly yourself - in all installation modes (install, uninstall, repair, modify, patch, upgrade). I am not set up for proper testing.

As an example, **Installshield's default launch condition** of `DOTNETVERSION20="#1"` - for the .NET framework version 2 - would seem to trigger an un-uninstallable package if the dot net version in question is ever uninstalled (I assume the registry key will be missing then, but I didn't have the time to actually test). Adding **Installed** as an **OR-condition** - like WiX does it - seems to alleviate the problem.

---

***Links:***

- [Check if prerequisites are installed before installing a windows installer package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121149/check-if-prerequisites-are-installed-before-installing-a-windows-installer-packa/55183152#55183152)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Answer (score 1):

The newer prerequisites are now available as an update to InstallShield 2018. Goto Tools -> Check For Updates to get them

Answer (score 1):

You can add this file:
[Condition file](http://saturn.installshield.com/is/prerequisites/Microsoft%20.NET%20Framework%204.7.2%20Full.prq)
to path: C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\20xx\SetupPrerequisites